# Mixpanel raw data export authentication error

Tags: jquery, ajax, token, mixpanel

I am currently trying to use export raw data from mixpanel, here is the url I am using:

[mixepanel Url](https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/?from_date=2016-06-26&expire=100000&sig=A3CD00A50FA2B9B30E6FFFFFADB6B0A2&api_key=80fjjjjjjjjjjjjf09a63c722a91250e&to_date=2016-07-15&where=%221543559%22%20%3D%3D%20properties%5B%22User%20Id%22%5D)

(the api key and sig are manipulated, not the real ones)

Here is my ajax code:

```
var api_key = 'xxx';
var api_secret = 'xxx';
var expire = 100000;
var from_date = $('#from').val();
var to_date = $('#to').val();
var sig = faultylabs.MD5("api_key=" + api_key + "expire=" + expire + "format=json" + api_secret);
var event = $('#event').val();
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
console.log(Base64.encode(api_secret));
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + Base64.encode(api_secret),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    data: {
        // event: '["Activate Device", "Screen View"]',
        from_date: from_date,
        expire: expire,
        sig: sig,
        api_key: api_key,
        to_date: to_date,
        where: '"'+user_id+'" == properties["User Id"]',
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
    },
    error: function (response) {console.log(response['statusText']);},
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, maybe some of you can help me out!